# C# adding empty literal in empty tablecell results in

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals, tablecell

I'm reading a menu control code. The code uses a tablerow in a table to construct the menu. After each menu item tablecell, it adds the code:

```
TableCell td = new TableCell();
Literal lt = new Literal();
td.Controls.Add(lt);
tr.Cells.Add(td);
```

And it results in a space between each menu item, when displaying the menu table.  I just wonder why it does that? Does an empty tablecell take space?

Comment: Probably, unless a style sheet dictates otherwise. On that note, controlling the rendering with a style sheet is a much better idea than adding more elements to the page and hoping everything works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed .NET adds in `&nbsp;` into empty cells, this has to be down to HTML tables getting a bit ugly looking with an empty cell; it won't get any border and can sometimes (depending on your styling) look rather weird. If you're wanting a gap between table cells use `cellspacing` or apply a style with `margin-right`.

On a side note it's recommended you be using `var` on the left side of your declarations (only when the right side clearly states what it is), ie:

```
var td = new TableCell();
var lt = new Literal();
td.Controls.Add(lt);
tr.Cells.Add(td);
```

You would **not** use it like this:

```
var x = GetMyVariable();
```